# How are command line commands stored in .bash_history?

Tags: bash

Command-line commands are collected in `.bash_history`. Fine! But not all. Often I close a terminal and try a day later to find a command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, but bash tells me "command not found". Why are some commands stored in history and some not? How can I prevent lost commands? I use OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: Read section [9.1 Bash History Facilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Facilities.html#Bash-History-Facilities) in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

The history size is controlled by the variables HISTFILESIZE and HISTSIZE (see `man bash`). The default value is 500.

You must store these parameters in `~/.bash_profile`

Example:

```
export HISTFILESIZE=5000
export HISTSIZE=5000
```